# Fitting UIWebView Content Horizontally and Vertically

Tags: html, css, uiwebview, xcode4.3

I have a UIWebview that loads a simple picture.The user needs to see the whole picture without the need of scrolling vertically. With the use of setSalesPageToFit:YES , The user had the image loaded but needed to scroll vertically to see the whole picture, how can i force the picture to show up entirely and no need to scrolling could be used?
This is my code snippet:

```
NSString *pathImg = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"1"] ofType:@"png"];
    NSString* webViewContent = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                @"<html>"
                                "<body style='background-color: transparent' >"
                                "<div align='center'>"
                                "<img src=\"file://%@\"/ style='align:center;'>"
                                "</div>"
                                "</body></html>", pathImg];
      webView.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];
    [self->webView loadHTMLString:webViewContent baseURL:nil];
    [webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
```

Any help will be highly appreciated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.. Hope it will help you

```
 NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:
              @"<html>"
              "<head>"
              "<script type=\"text/javascript\" >"
              "function display(img){"
              "var imgOrigH = document.getElementById('image').offsetHeight;"
              "var imgOrigW = document.getElementById('image').offsetWidth;"
              "var bodyH = window.innerHeight;"
              "var bodyW = window.innerWidth;"
              "if((imgOrigW/imgOrigH) > (bodyW/bodyH))"
              "{"
              "document.getElementById('image').style.width = bodyW + 'px';"
              "document.getElementById('image').style.top = (bodyH - document.getElementById('image').offsetHeight)/2  + 'px';"
              "}"
              "else"
              "{"
              "document.getElementById('image').style.height = bodyH + 'px';"
              "document.getElementById('image').style.marginLeft = (bodyW - document.getElementById('image').offsetWidth)/2  + 'px';"
              "}"
              "}"
              "</script>"
              "</head>"
              "<body style=\"margin:0;width:100%;height:100%;\" >"
              "<img id=\"image\" src=\"%@\" onload=\"display()\" style=\"position:relative\" />"
              "</body>"
              "</html>",image path];

     [webView setClipsToBounds:YES];
    webView.opaque=NO;
    webView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [webView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    [webView sizeToFit];
    [webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
    [webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply it did work but with a problem! My image now is on the right...how can i keep it centered ? I tried <div align='center'> but no luck

Comment: but it works perfectly for me and my image displayed center of the webview

Comment: to have no scrolling i had to remove the " /2 " factor from your suggestion, and when i removed them the image correctly loaded but too much on the right..what do you think i am doing wrong?

Comment: dont remove "/2" factor just use as it is

Comment: if i use it as it is, the image will still load with the option of scrolling because it won't fit vertically, and in the same time it has a position extremely to the right, now if i remove the " /2 " , it will load correctly fitted vertically but still too much on the right...what do you think

Comment: Did u use this [webView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

Comment: Yes i did, but note that i actually need the possibility to zoom, i just want it when it loads to loads fitted horizontally and vertically, like shrinking the image to fit the webview

Comment: Did you create webview programmatically or in Xib

Comment: I created the web view using storyboard , it has the following dimensions :
Width : 1024 , Height : 580 , X : 0 and Y : 129 with the arrow at first upper left field

Comment: I can't understand why this happening but its really works for me and i used it many times.